# NHibernate: How to test a many-to-one relationship is lazy?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I've got a simple many-to-one relationship (an Order has a Customer who placed it).  Here's the except from my Order mapping:

```
<many-to-one name="Customer" column="FK_CUSTOMERS" class="MyApp.Customer, MyApp" 
not-null="true" lazy="proxy" cascade="none" />
```

Yet the following does not pass:

```
configuration.GetClassMapping(typeof(Order))
  .ReferenceablePropertyIterator.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Name=="Customer")
  .IsLazy
  .ShouldBeTrue();
```

What gives?

Comment: Don't you want to check IsLazy on the property named "Customer"?

Comment: You're right - I just mistyped - the error still happens.  Editted.

Comment: What does Customer look like? (code)

Comment: @Mauricio - as you might guess this is a contrived example but all my entities use dynamic-components so they have an IDictionary property and an Id.  An Order has a many to one relationship to Customer and a customer has a many to one to FavoriteOnlineStore - nothing more complicated than that.  Are you saying that my test should be passing and that there might be something else overriding the setting?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the source and it seems NH treats IsLazy kind of weird. Here was the last change on 2010-01-26

```
get
            {
-               if (propertyValue is ToOne)
-               {
-                   // both many-to-one and one-to-one are represented as a
-                   // Property.  EntityPersister is relying on this value to
-                   // determine "lazy fetch groups" in terms of field-level
-                   // interception.  So we need to make sure that we return
-                   // true here for the case of many-to-one and one-to-one
-                   // with lazy="no-proxy"
-                   //
-                   // * impl note - lazy="no-proxy" currently forces both
-                   // lazy and unwrap to be set to true.  The other case we
-                   // are extremely interested in here is that of lazy="proxy"
-                   // where lazy is set to true, but unwrap is set to false.
-                   // thus we use both here under the assumption that this
-                   // return is really only ever used during persister
-                   // construction to determine the lazy property/field fetch
-                   // groupings.  If that assertion changes then this check
-                   // needs to change as well.  Partially, this is an issue with
-                   // the overloading of the term "lazy" here...
-                   ToOne toOneValue = (ToOne)propertyValue;
-                   return toOneValue.IsLazy && toOneValue.UnwrapProxy;
-               }
+               // NH Specific: Hibernate doesn't make a distinction between
+               // lazy and no-proxy, but NHibernate does. While Hibernate tracks
+               // just whatever a property is lazy, we need to track lazy/no-proxy seperatedly.
+               
                return isLazy;
            }
```

So it depends on the version you are using, but it looks like 2009 versions only return true for this property if you mapped it as `noproxy` (ie. UnwrapProxy). What does this give you?

```
var to1 = configuration.GetClassMapping(typeof(Order))
  .ReferenceablePropertyIterator.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Name=="Customer")
  .Value as NHibernate.Mapping.ToOne;

to1.IsLazy.ShouldBeTrue();
to1.UnwrapProxy.ShouldBeFalse();
```